# How can I install the Octave 4.2 documentation using Homebrew?

Tags: command-line, installation, homebrew, octave

I tried installing Octave (4.2) from the command line using

```
brew install octave
```

but this does not install documentation. When I run octave, I get the following error:

```
octave:1> doc
error: doc: unable to find the Octave info manual, Octave installation is incomplete
```

Some googling indicated that I should instead run

```
brew install octave --with-docs
```

but this returns

```
Warning: octave: this formula has no --with-docs option so it will be ignored!
```

How can I install the Octave docs from the command line?

Answer (score 1):

this is really delayed but since this came up in my search results, the reason if you still don't know yet is that the latest version of Octave on Homebrew is just octave-cli.

One would need to change the repo brew taps to to an older version to get the GUI.

Although, I'm thinking on sticking with the cli version for a while right now since I can still plot and stuff.